importlib.import_module() imports modules from multiple subfolders, but only the top-level directory is recognized
I use importlib.import_module() to import modules from different folders, but it only recognizes the top-level directory name. This is my environment.
There are three folders a, b, and c in the test directory
(py312) root@ubuntu2004-host:~# tree test/
test/
├── a
│   ├── aa
│   │   └── aaa
│   │       └── aaaa
│   └── a.py
├── b
└── c
    └── cxxx.py

6 directories, 2 files

The code of a.py is as follows
import importlib
import sys

print(sys.path)
params=importlib.import_module('c.cxxx')
params.args
params.C

The code of c.py is as follows
args = {'a': 1}

class C:
def C(self):
  pass

When executing a.py, it always reports the error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'c', which means that the directory c is recognized instead of the module cxxx
(py312) root@ubuntu2004-host:~/test# python3.12 a/a.py 
['/root/test/a', '/usr/lib/python312.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.12', '/usr/lib/python3.12/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python3.12/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/test/a/a.py", line 5, in <module>
    params=importlib.import_module('c.cxxx')
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.12/importlib/__init__.py", line 90, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1387, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1360, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1310, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 488, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1387, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1360, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1324, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'c'

The original python version was 3.11. I also tried Python 3.12.4 and 3.8, but they also gave the same error.

Hi. And what is your question then? The /root/test is not in path, there is no such module in path, all checks out. You even print the path, so you see what is in there.
